# UIColor colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha: always returning a red-tinted color

Tags: iphone, ios, uicolor

If I plug in HSB values of 0.667, 1, 1 into the code below, it should return a blue color.  However, it returns red.  I have verified that 0.667 should be a blue hue by using a rgb-to-hsb converter.  Playing with different values for this method always seems to return a red-tinted color.  What am I missing here?

```
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue: 0.667 
                                      saturation: 1.0 
                                      brightness: 1.0 
                                           alpha: 1.0];
```

Comment: I tried your code and it did indeed produce a bright blue background. There must be some other code in your app interfering somehow.

Comment: Could you use `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];` instead?

Does `colorWithHue:` take values in the range 0-360?

Comment: Webster:  I can't use the RGB method in my actual implementation, because I am trying to adjust a design element's hue slightly.  That's what led me to this problem.

Comment: Picciano: I am using the XCode 4.3 beta, it's possible that this is a bug there, in which case I will need to head over to the Apple beta forums since it is under NDA.  I thought it unlikely that this was a bug in the beta, since I tested it on my iOS 4 phone and I saw the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, it was due to a category method I had defined on UIColor with the same name.  Now that UIColor supports the method, the previously working category method somehow interfered with the Apple implementation.